# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string (?)

Tags: c#, sql

When I clicked Submit button , it will pop-out a message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

This is my code in Submit Button :

```
string date = DateLabel.Text;
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);

con.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TrHeaderTransaction VALUES ('"+ transID +"', '"+ emploID +"','"+ custID +"','"+DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()+"', '"+ totPrice +"')");


// my code for convert date to string
private void displayDate() 
{
    DateLabel.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.ToString().Substring(0,10);
}
```

Comment: Please use bind parameters when working with SQL commands.

Comment: What is the text that it is trying to convert?

Comment: Yes... parameters... especially for dates and times. Date and time formats are very, very complex things. Local representation can vary a lot depending on locale and user settings. But RDBMS do not know about these local settings and may have to manage requests that come from all over the world. Different RDBMS handle datetime conversion in different ways. But parameters know these differences and can handle this complexity for you. And parameters provide other advantages, like protection from SQL injection, allowing for statement preparation in case you need to reexecute the same statement.

Comment: I think you keep your date values in a character typed column. Don't do that!

Comment: firstly you're not using the date from the date label but instead using DateTime.Now(), also read up on sql injection and reformat your SQL to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Use directly the date fonction for now in SQL statement instead of trying to convert it from `C#` to `SQL`.

- In sql server it's `GETDATE()`
- In oracle it's `SYSDATE`
- In MySql it's `NOW()`

Ex : `con.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TrHeaderTransaction VALUES ('"+ transID +"', '"+ emploID +"','"+ custID +"', GETDATE(), '"+ totPrice +"')");`